# UI design for list of time

Tags: gui-design, visual-design

I am developing mobile app for checking transport time for bus service. Basically there will be different 'routes' and they will have regular schedule of bus trips. When user selects any route, app will show all trips available for that route. Currently I am using following UI design.

[image]

Now problem is, this design is fine when there are only 2 different trip schedule for given route. How can I make it more modular so that if there are multiple schedules (for example each day of week will be different) or single one (one schedule for all days of week). Any better suggestions or criticism are welcome.

Comment: Any idea what the anticipated upper limit is for different schedules?

Comment: Also, the next trip from now doesn't seem to make sense, or maybe it does if that's the first transport available from 11:56, i.e. 1pm?

Comment: Why show more than one day? When I take a bus, I take my journey all on the same day. Let them select the day prior or ON the page, using a simple selection (dropdown) [Korea has the best Bus app possible.](http://a1.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple111/v4/0d/16/0a/0d160a83-53c4-a2e5-5136-49493472f1ee/screen696x696.jpeg).

Comment: @UXfrom12, upper limit will be 7 (days of week). But mostly it will be either 2 or 1. I am just preparing for any changes in future. My app calculates next transport after current time and highlight it accordingly.

Comment: @insidesin, That is true. In most of the cases it is only 2 schedules, hence i showed them all. But I was not able to come up with any good UI design to show user that there are different schedules also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm reading your problem right, this looks clearer to me, although I may not be understanding why you show a complete list of times and highlight when there's one available, if that is the case, I wouldn't show times for when there isn't an option.

[image: Bus Timetable]

Comment: Thank for the departing, arriving suggestion. However how will I design UI if I want to indicate user that this is not every day's schedule and it will be different in different days (or Sunday in above case)

Comment: Perhaps with a day switcher, left and right for next day, next day etc. the list would then update to reflect those journey times.